# sql range operator

Tags: sql

Is there a SQL construct or a trick to do something like:

```
SELECT i WHERE i BETWEEN 0 AND 10;
```

?

My first idea is to create a temporary table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE _range ( i INT PRIMARY KEY );
```

and fill it

```
INSERT INTO _range VALUES 0;
INSERT INTO _range VALUES 1;
```

etc.

Is there a better way?

UPDATE:

I use sqlite in this particular case but i am interested in general answer.

Comment: Do you need this as restriction for some other query?

Comment: @Goran Rakic: Yes exactly. I have two tables I need to join (T1, T2). They do not contain date. Then I have a very complicated predicate which matches records of T1 to records of T2. The predicate depends on values of T1, T2 and on two dates D1 and D2. Date D1 is given as a paremeter, D2 may be in range D1 to D1+10.

Comment: Why not restrict D2 using (D2 >= D1 AND D2 =< D1+10)? If there is no D2 = D1+5 you do not need to check if D2 is D1+5 (your idea of using range), you are interesting only in those D2 values which are in range and this can be done with restriction. Another thing would be if you need NULLs for missing D2 values from the range but this can be added in application logic too, avoiding temp table.

Comment: The values of D1 and D2 are NOT in any table. They are only arguments of a complicated function containing also the values of T1 and T2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question.  Here's an ugly hack that probably is useless unless your ranges are really that small...

```
select * from (
  select 1 as num  UNION 
  select 2 as num  UNION 
  select 3 as num  UNION 
  select 4 as num  UNION 
  select 5 as num  UNION 
  select 6 as num  UNION 
  select 7 as num  UNION 
  select 8 as num  UNION 
  select 9 as num  UNION 
  select 10 as num
  ) t ;

+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   1 | 
|   2 | 
  .... 
|   9 | 
|  10 | 
+-----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit:  Ok, so I got to thinking why not use cross joins.  So, here is another hack and this one will quickly net you pretty large in memory tables and is perhaps reasonably good.

```
select POW(2,0)*t0.num + POW(2,1)*t1.num + POW(2,2)*t2.num + POW(2,3)*t3.num  
as num 
from (
  select 0 as num  UNION 
  select 1 as num  
  ) t0, (
  select 0 as num  UNION 
  select 1 as num  
  ) t1, (
  select 0 as num  UNION 
  select 1 as num  
  ) t2, (
  select 0 as num  UNION 
  select 1 as num  
  ) t3 
order by num ;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    0 | 
|    1 | 
  ....
|   14 | 
|   15 | 
+------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Will easily go to any power of 2 and should be fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

What DB are you using? The between operator generally is legal syntax for SQL. We use it all the time for date ranges.

from http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_between.asp

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Comment: I do not want to use BETWEEN for testing values (which is quite common), I want to generate values of i (see anshul's answer).

Answer (score 1):

with **MS SQL** you could use **CTE** :

```
;with numbs as
(
    select 1 as col 
    union all
    select col + 1 from numbs
    where col < 10
)

select * from numbs
```

Comment: This works, but bare in mind that you're limited to 100 recursions.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the dbms you use, but with `Oracle` you could use `CONNECT BY`:

```
SELECT ROWNUM-1 i
FROM dual
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An SQL syntax that multiply records is [CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx)
I am not sure from your request and comments, but I guess you are trying to do that.

I have done a similar thing to populate a table with a datestamp as string "YYYYMM" for a period of 20 years.

Comment: How do you generate range between 1 and 10 using cross join without creating temporary tables?